# Button at the bottom of ScrollView with ListView inside

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout, something like a page. I have a list view and at the bottom of the list i need to have a button. It has to be **under** the List View, not sticking at the bottom of the screen. (Like you have to scroll all the way down through the list to get that button.) The structure I am using:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/show_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:dividerHeight="7dp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="25dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:scrollingCache="false" />
        <LinearLayout>
           //My button here
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**MAIN ISSUE:** Scrolling ends at the last item of ListView, Button stays out of screen. Why is that so? (*I tried disabling list scrolling with **isVerticalScrollBarEnabled**, but it didn't make any difference.*)

**EDIT:** Now, as I switched order of the button and the list, I found out that I am scrolling ListView, not ScrollView, so the issue is I need to do scrolling of ScrollView, not ListView. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that ListView in a ScrollView is a bad practice, I used ListView footer feature instead, having button in the seperate layout, then adding it through code. It works perfectly.